# My partition table is messed up

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem

My partition table is messed up. Here are the screenshots of all outputs gpt fdisk and diskutil.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't boot to my mac os not bootcamp i lost them and i want to get them back , i tried it before and it was working

Comment: I used to have 4 partitions before

Comment: 1-macintosh 2-recovery hd 3- bootcamp 4-ee

Comment: Plz suggest steps to fix this situation starting with bogus mbr

Comment: Please add any important detail in the **question** by editing it. Afterwards delete your comments. Also add how you got (or lost) these additional (or missing) partitions.

Comment: I don't know how i get them but you can see from tye size of tgese partitions they are recovery partition, based on this gpt table diskutil is able to repair the disk but i still  can't boot!!